# Include ASP.NET Label / Span as part of form postback?

Tags: html, asp.net

Is it possible to include non form elements into the postback data in an ASP.NET form? I have a business application that's a very large entry grid with potentially upwards of 10,000 input boxes in a single view. Essentially each cell is an input like a spreadsheet.

Pagination has to be kept to a minimum due to the way the information is structured and for productivity. Even with all of the inputs, Chrome loads the page in under a second, IE takes an unacceptable 20+ due to the number of elements.

Because of IE, I experimented with a code that temporarily converts a TD from Label into Input and back into Label which reduces the load time to nearly instantly since there aren't any inputs initially rendered. Though the question is how then (if possible) to send the Label values on postback?

All of the ASP.NET Labels are created dynamically and the data table is created from scratch due to its complexity with total columns and special rows.

Comment: The only way I can see is to put eh information inside an input type hidden.

Comment: What I have done in the past for this type of form is use AJAX to submit dynamic fields to a web service. A little bit of javascript and you can gather all of the check box values or what have you extremely quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I might look into that

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do that is to use javascript to create a postback manually, but that would be a ton of work, depending on how you are doing everything.